# Query nested object array for property with Realm

Tags: objective-c, realm

I've been trying to write a query to access an object equal to a specific key for a while without success. I've already looked through SO & Realm documentation without any luck.

If I print out the structure of the CachedCodes  RLMObject, it looks like this:

```
CachedCodes {
    Codes = Codes {
            assets = RLMArray<KVString> (
                [0] KVString {
                    key = Some Key;// this is what I'd want to query for
                    value = Some Value;
                }
            );
        };
}
```

Here's my class structure:

```
@interface CachedCodes : RLMObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) Codes *Codes;//readwrite in .m
@end

@interface Codes : RLMObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) RLMArray<KVString *><KVString> *assets;//readwrite in .m
@end

@interface KVString : RLMObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *key;//readwrite in .m
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *value;//readwrite in .m
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(KVString);
```

Here's what I've tried:

`[CachedObjects objectsWhere:@"Codes.assets.key == 'Some key'"];`

Error: Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations.

`[CachedObjects objectsWhere:@"Codes.assets.key IN 'Some key'"];`

Error: Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations.

`[CachedObjects objectsWhere:@"ANY Codes.assets.key == 'Some key'"];`

Error: No error. It doesn't crash, nor does it give me the objects with key "Some key". Instead, it gives me all of the objects.

If anyone has any input, I'd be forever grateful :)

Comment: To be clear, you expect the query to return a `KVString` object whose value for `key` matches your desired string?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some back-and-forth discussion, modified solution is presented here. The long and the short of it is that Realm provides a way to grab inner-nested objects of a specific type within a realm directly without having to worry so much about the exact key-path to get there.

```
RLMResults<KVString *> *results = [KVString objectsWhere:@"key == 'SomeKey'"];
```

Comment: Returns the same thing :/. `Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations`

Comment: Ah, whoops, "aggregate operation" means "ANY" or "ALL". Updated the code (sorry, not able to test this personally at the moment)

Comment: It says that "ALL" is not supported. "ANY" however, doesn't crash but returns me the whole list unfiltered.

Comment: If the above code doesn't work, I'll refrain from posting any further until I have a chance to do some working, tested code. *Might* have to use the predicate `SUBQUERY` command to dig into your nested array.

Comment: That seems to crash: `Unsupported collection operation '@unionOfObjects'`

Comment: I don't disagree with you :) Something fishy is going on here, and I'm not sure what the problem is. I'll update my question with the exact structure of the objects.

Comment: I switched to a nested array (not my decision, API structure calls for it), in which regard the predicate suggestions you helped out with don't make a difference, unfortunately. Nonetheless, I updated my question with the new structure & complete object interfaces.

Comment: I'm having success with the following syntax
`RLMResults<KVString *> *results = [KVString objectsWhere:@"key == 'SomeKey'"];`

It seems that this will ask Realm to look for the type of object you're interested in, without having to worry about the nesting structure so rigidly. When I do this, I correctly get one and only one objects whose value matches expectations.

Comment: That works! Thank you for your assistance. Please update your answer so I could approve it